# How to fetch the data from a List type of future call and a simple future call in one program in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have tried calling a list  and a simple future in a single program and I also searched for this in the web I didn't get a solution

**studentDetails.dart**

```
Future<List<Stud>> studentDetails(http.Client client, var lin) async {
  print(lin);
  //Codes 
  return studList;
}
```

**fetchhistory.dart**

```
Future<AttendanceHistory> fetchhistory(http.Client client, String id) async {
  //codes
  return parsedJson;
}
```

I want these service file to be called in one component file.

**studentView.dart**

```
 // Scaffold codes

 body: FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([
      studentDetails(http.Client(), widget.sid),
      
      fetchhistory(http.Client(), widget.sid),
    ]),
    builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          //  lab: widget.label
          ? StudListView(
              stud: snapshot.data[0],
              his:snapshot.data[1]
            )
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),

 //scaffold codes
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image: Errors]

I have the only problem in the implementation that how can I use 2 service calls inside the Body of the Scaffold Please help me because I am seriously tended to solve this error.
Thank you

Comment: I didn't run the code but this is what I was trying ...

Comment: Put cursor on error code and add error to the question?

Comment: it is solved by including an import file.Thanks